# Django filter all querysets based on requestor

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way with a Manager or another method that would allow me to filter all querysets on some field based on the current requestor so that I don't have to explicitly do it everytime?

Comment: An object manager is located in the "model layer". So in good design, it should not know anything about the view. Especially since one can make model changes *without* views. You could analyze the *call stack*, but that would be a very ugly way of doing it. You can make your program stateful, but that is a huge antipattern. So strictly speaking, it *is* possible, but not a good idea.

Comment: Maybe you could be more specific, giving an example of what you're doing now, where the filter is used multiple times. That would help us give you an alternative to filtering on the Manger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `**kwargs` syntax to convert any dict-like object to the function's argument list.  For example filtering queryset by all fields from request's GET parameters will look like this:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(**request.GET)
```

But this code is very insecure, so you should sanitize the `request.GET` data before passing it to the `filter()`.